# To much FPS drop

Tags: actionscript-3

http://www.fastswf.com/USUAp00

When i scale my procedural generated map based off a perlin noise map to a bigger size, so i can place a character on the map and actually navigate it (moving the map around the player instead of the player around the map), it gets major fps drop.
Test for yourself with the provided link, the higher the scale or map width/height is increased the more it lags while walking. I understand this is allot of data blocks to move

Is there a better way to go about moving my player around?
Would adding the spawned objects to an object pool help? I don't think it would

Is it possible to split the map into segments after generation and load certain segments based off your x,y?

World class: //handles spawning the map
http://pastebin.com/CfMDBWeR

Level class: // handles moving the map around

```
public class Level extends MovieClip
{
    var world:World;
    protected var goin:Vector.<int> = new Vector.<int>();
    protected var moveSpeed:int;
    protected var MAP_SCALE:int;


    public function Level()
    {
        MAP_SCALE = GlobalCode.MAP_SCALE;
        trace("level")
        for(var i:int = 0; i < 4; i++){
            goin[i]=0;
        }
        world = new World(this);
        addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, update);
        addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
        addEventListener(Event.REMOVED_FROM_STAGE, cleanUp);
        moveSpeed = 10;
        // constructor code
    }
    protected function init(e:Event)
    {
        stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, keyPressed);
        stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, keyReleased);
    }
    protected function cleanUp(e:Event)
    {
        stage.removeEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, keyPressed);
        stage.removeEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, keyReleased);
    }
    protected function keyPressed(k:KeyboardEvent)
    {
        if (k.keyCode == Keyboard.W)
        {
            goin[0] = 1;
        }
        if (k.keyCode == Keyboard.S)
        {
            goin[1] = 1;
        }
        if (k.keyCode == Keyboard.A)
        {
            goin[2] = 1;
        }
        if (k.keyCode == Keyboard.D)
        {
            goin[3] = 1;
        }
    }
    protected function MovePlayer(){
        if (goin[0] == 1)
        {
            world.worldTiles.y +=  moveSpeed;
        }
        if (goin[1] == 1)
        {
            world.worldTiles.y -=  moveSpeed;
        }
        if (goin[2] == 1)
        {
            world.worldTiles.x +=  moveSpeed;
        }
        if (goin[3] == 1)
        {
            world.worldTiles.x -=  moveSpeed;
        }
    }

    protected function keyReleased(k:KeyboardEvent)
    {
        if (k.keyCode == Keyboard.W)
        {
            goin[0] = 0;
        }
        if (k.keyCode == Keyboard.S)
        {
            goin[1] = 0;
        }
        if (k.keyCode == Keyboard.A)
        {
            goin[2] = 0;
        }
        if (k.keyCode == Keyboard.D)
        {
            goin[3] = 0;
        }
    }
    public function update(e:Event)
    {
        world.worldTiles.scaleX = MAP_SCALE;
        world.worldTiles.scaleY = MAP_SCALE;
        MovePlayer();
    }
}
```

Stage Class: The class actually connected to the stage, handles frame switching

```
public class Stage extends MovieClip {
    private var targetFrame:String;

    public function Stage() {
        targetFrame = "Menu";
        // constructor code
    }
    private function gotoLabel(desiredLabel:String)
    {
        for (var i=0; i<currentLabels.length; i++)
        {
            if (currentLabels[i].name == desiredLabel)
            {
                gotoAndPlay(desiredLabel);
                return;
            }
        }
        trace("Requested frame missing!");
    }
    public function generateMap(m:MouseEvent){
        GlobalCode.TILE_SIZE = int(tileSizeText.text);
        GlobalCode.MAP_HEIGHT = int(mapHeightText.text);
        GlobalCode.MAP_WIDTH = int(mapWidthText.text);
        GlobalCode.MAP_SCALE = int(mapScaleText.text);
        gotoLabel("Game");
    }
    private function doneLoading(m:MouseEvent)
    {
        //set targetFrame
        gotoLabel("Menu");
    }
  }
```

Comment: "Is it possible to split the map into segments after generation and load certain segments based off your x,y?" - the only real solution, because otherwise your app needs to render all that visual object, despite the fact that it's not actually visible. The bigger it gets, the more memory it takes (depends on how you draw it, but you get the idea). Split and rule :)

Comment: So i guess my goal now is to figure out how to do that :D im sure i can handle it maybe hopefully maybe